# npm install code 1 error git dep preparation failed

Tags: npm

Has anyone hit the error below when trying to install NPM?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /home/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/bin/node /home/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/home/user1/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! The git reference could not be found
npm ERR! npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects checkout 4.0
npm ERR! npm ERR! error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     /home/user1/.npm/_logs/2021-07-27T07_22_59_809Z-debug.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user1/.npm/_logs/2021-07-27T07_24_31_341Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got that error while using node v16.13.0. After I switched to v10.24.1, it got solved.

Comment: This isn't a valid solution since node will eventually need to be updated, in which the problem will come back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on In Windows 10 with node 16.

For me, the solution was either running commands

```
set NODE_ENV=development
$env:NODE_ENV="development"
```

or calling the `npm install` command with **admin rights** inside PowerShell

By the way, when I switched to node v12, it worked for me as well.